# How to BR with nzp=000 in LC3

Tags: lc3

I tried to write the inst `x0000` which means `BR` with `nzp=0` and offset `0`.

I wrote `BR #0` in the simulator.

Instead of giving me that `x0000` on the simulator,
I get `0x0E00` which means `nzp` is `111`.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What is your intention?  Just to fill space with zeroes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `NOP` because if `nzp=000` it means that the PC won't change, so you just need to pass this instruction.

Another option is do `LABEL .fill x0000` because the instruction code of `BR` with `nzp=0` and offset `0` will be just `000`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `nzp=000`. A number is either negative, zero or positive.

According to [this course on LC3 from UPenn](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cit593/cit593f09/lectures/lc3ISAII.pdf)

> LC-3 has three 1-bit condition code registers
>
> - N - negative
> - Z - zero
> - P - positive (greater than zero)
>
> Exactly one will be set at all times.
>   Based on the last instruction that altered a register.

Answer (score 0):

`BR` will assemble to branch-always, which is exactly the same as `BRnzp`, which is why you're seeing that in the assembled code.